# unable to connect Android phone to Adhoc mode

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am not able to connect to an open AD-HOC network i created on my laptop on Windows 7 and trying to connect using my samsung galaxy i9000. I followed exactly the same procedure described above but i cant get it to work. Please help. Is there anything else i need to add for OPEN adhoc network?
(Android#),

Answer (score 5):

Last time I looked into this issue Android did not support Ad-Hoc networks on stock ROMs. Maybe this has already been fixed in Android 4.x but for all versions prior to 4.x it simply did not work.

You can get working Ad-Hoc support if you root your phone and install the [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) ROM.

If you don't want to root and change ROMs, an alternative would be to create a standard Wifi hotspot instead of an ad-hoc network.

On Windows this could be achieved using programs like [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) or without any additional programs (on Windows 7 only) using the built-in system tools as described at http://www.ishanarora.com/2009/07/29/windows-7-as-a-wireless-access-point/.

On OSX you can enable WiFi hotspot from <kbd>System preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Sharing</kbd> > <kbd>Internet Sharing: Wi-Fi</kbd>, and on a Linux machine you can use the [hostapd](https://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/) daemon (if your Wi-Fi adapter supports it).

And the last, and probably the best solution, would be to get a wifi router.

Comment: Hi ccpizza, thanks for getting back to me. I took your advice and got connectify working. I connected two wifi modules to the hotspot and also connected my android phone to it. I have another question if you can help me. My android phone has a simple server application running and two wifi modules act as clients and connect to my server. Now how do i send a message individually to each client. Eg. I want to send "abc" to module1 and send "xyz" to module2. Is that even possible using a server? If it is how do i implement it.

Comment: @David Norman: You send whatever you need to send to the specific IP address of each module. But since you are using a server that works as a PULL event, i.e. a server cannot PUSH a message to a specific client, it only responds to whoever happened to access the URL.

Comment: I tried using methods from wifip2p library to communicate directly to a wifi enabled device but it wouldn't work because I have android v2.3 and this library wouldn't work for versions below v3.2

Answer (score 1):

Android does not support adhoc wifi

=> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82

But you have some alternative wpa_supplicant files available that let you connect to adhoc wifi. They are known to cause bugs and instability.

Comment: Hi Estragon.. I have rooted my android phone and changed the wpa_supplicant file and also wpa_supplicant.conf. I could see the adhoc network on the scan network list but when i try to connect to it, it just gets stuck saying 'obtaining IP address' and then it disconnects. I know it has for some people but i guess im not one of them. thanks for your help tho. cheers

Comment: Well, maybe it can help you : cyanogenmod 9 for I9000 supports adhoc wifi since 1 or 2 weeks. You should give it a try : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1387937 (read doc before flashing, its a total different rom (based on 4.04 android sources) and it will wipe all your data upon flash)